# C# parameters date based on day of week

Tags: c#

I want to insert a date in parameters:

- If current day is Monday is Friday
- If current Tuesday day is Monday
- If current day is Wednesday choose Tuesday
- If current day is Thursday choose the environment
- If current day is Friday to select Thursday
- If current Saturday day is selected on Friday
- If current Sunday day is Friday

I have a method that selects date according to my condition above

```
public static DateTime GetDateBackDayStart(DateTime date)
{
    int numweek = GetNumWeek(date.DayOfWeek.ToString());
    if (numweek == 1)
    {
        return date.AddDays(-3).Date;
    }
    if (numweek == 7)
    {
        return date.AddDays(-2).Date;
    }
    else
    {
        return date.AddDays(-1).Date;
    }
}
```

I have a command that returns date in format:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

How to write condition of date substitution in parameters @date1  @date2 in format "dd.MM.yyyy" using the method GetDateBackDayStart?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and what problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

first call `GetDateBackDayStart` method, then `ToString` method on resulting date:

```
string dateParam = GetDateBackDayStart(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateParam;
```